# Clarification on hash++

Tags: perl, operators

I am reading Damian Conway's "Perl Best Practices" and found the following code snipet:

```
$have_reconsidered{lc($name)}++;
```

I am trying to figure out what is going on here with the hash. I know `++` increments by one in a numeric context, but what does it do to a hash?

From [perlop documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html):

> undef is always treated as numeric,
>   and in particular is changed to 0
>   before incrementing (so that a
>   post-increment of an undef value will
>   return 0 rather than undef). The
>   auto-decrement operator is not
>   magical.

So in the example above, is the value for the key `lc($name)` being initialized to `0` and then incremented to `1` by `++`?

In general, where could I find out more about the behaviors of `++`, `+=`, etc...?

Comment: In the statement, `$hash{key}++`, `++` is operating on the element of the hash, not the hash itself.  `%hash++` is not allowed.  the only less than obvious bit is that if `$hash{key}` doesn't exist, it is instantiated to 0 then incremented.  This will happen with `+=`, `.=` creates an empty string and appends to it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`%have_reconsidered` is your hash. `$name` is a string. `lc($name)` returns the lowercased string. `$hash{$key}` will return the scalar value from hash `%hash` stored with key `$key`. so:

```
// get scalar value from hash at key lc($name) and post-increment it
$have_reconsidered(lc($name)}++;
```

so, all you do is increment the value in a hash at a given index (namely `lc($name)`)

test case:

```
#!/bin/env perl
my %hash = ( 'a' => '2' );
my $name = 'A';
print $hash{lc($name)}++; // prints 2 (incremented after statement)
print $hash{lc($name)};   // prints 3
print ++$hash{lc($name)}; // prints 4 (incremented before statement)
```

Comment: @knittl: I understood that, but in the context the code appeared in (which I know I did not include in my question), the value for the key `lc($name)` did not seem to be defined or addressed before.

Comment: @YGomez: you should then include the original code in your question. what's the value of $name?

Comment: @knittl: The value of name doesn't matter. It's more the value of `$hash{lc($name)}`. I think I understood from your response though. If the value of `$hash{lc($name)}` is defined, then it will be incremented by `1`. Else it will be initialized to `1`, yes?

Comment: @YGomez: else it will be initialized to 0, then incremented by 1. you can add new keys to hashes, that's the beauty of it. perl will even create all variables on the fly if they didn't exist before. you can `use strict` to avoid such _mistakes_

Comment: @knittl: Is there an advanced reference to `++` and similar constructs?

Comment: @YGomez: why do you need an advanced referene to `++`? it should all be in `perlref perlop` linked in your question (you basically gave the answer yourself).

Comment: @knittl: The advanced reference is more to feed further curiosity. I am trying to grasp intricacies in behavior in perl.

Comment: This isn't intricacies so much as the combination of two simple features...`++` and using a hash element in a modifiable context.  You aren't going to find documentation that iterates through all the possible combinations of different features.

Answer (score 3):

Hash values are scalars, so `$have_reconsidered{lc($name)}++;` increments the *scalar* `$have_reconsidered{lc($name)}`. If that scalar was previously undefined or didn't exist, `++` will set it to 1.

The goal of this code is probably to remove duplicates.

```
>perl -E"++$seen{$_} for qw( a a a b c a d ); say keys %seen;"
cabd
```

I prefer a similar but different approach because it preserves order.

```
>perl -E"say grep !$seen{$_}++, qw( a a a b c a d );"
abcd
```

Comment: From perlop: "Note that just as in C, Perl doesn't define when the variable is incremented or decremented" Could you please explain the difference between your two sample codes?

Comment: @YGomez, In the first, the result is extracted from the hash. In the latter, the result is a filtering of the original list.

Answer (score 0):

$have_reconsidered{lc($name)} is the value of the hash %have_reconsidered that belongs to the key lc($name).  This value could definitely be numeric, but even if it is a string, it can still be auto-incremented (see http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Auto-increment-and-Auto-decrement).